# How to filter Facebook Ads Insights by time range?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm getting info about my ads throug the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/act_<ad_account_ID>?fields=ads{insights{ad_name,clicks}}` but returns data from the last 30 days, and I need to get information just about a specific time range. How can I do it? I'm trying to use the parameter `time_range={'since':'2021-09-01','until':'2021-09-03'}` but doesn't work.

By the way, I tried to use the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/act_<ad_account_ID>/insights?level=ad&fields=ad_name,clicks&time_range={'since':'2021-09-01','until':'2021-09-03'}` and it works the way I need, but when all the fields needed are passed (using ad_name and clicks just as an example) it returns an error about the amount of data returned, saying it's too much, and it doesn't occur in the other endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my experience it is useful to select carefully the metrics, avoiding the redundant ones and to perform asynchronous or, better, batch requests; if you have to retrieve lot of data please switch to these kind of methods and avoid sincrhonous requests.

You can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices/).

I suggest you moreover to avoid insights data call at account level; it is better to pass a bunch of ids and make batch call.

Comment: I'm using the insights endpoint but now doing it asynchronous and works just the way I want! Thank you.